# Running apt upgrade downgrades kernel from `4.8.0.40.51` to `4.8.0.39.50`

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, kernel, downgrade

When executing `apt upgrade` (after running update first), is displays information that packages `linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev` are going to be downgraded.

**Should I proceed, or something is wrong with dependencies?**

My current dist is `16.10`, with `4.8.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP` kernel.

Here's full command output:

```
[~]$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php7.1 php-cli php-common php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysql php-tidy php-xml
  php-zip php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-dev php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-json
  php7.0-mbstring php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-curl
  php7.1-dev php7.1-fpm php7.1-gd php7.1-intl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql
  php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline php7.1-tidy php7.1-xml php7.1-zip snap-confine snapd thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us
  thunderbird-locale-pl
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
47 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 64,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1459 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Did you add any PPA?

Comment: Yes, I have around 20 ppa's, had no such problem previously. Maybe should I simply not upgrade yet?

Comment: So the problem is with some of the added PPA. You need to look int them and find out what is the dependency problem. It is not a good idea to add many PPA when you have no idea what is there.

Comment: I need many PPA's, because I need some packages in latest versions. What bugs me is that it tries to downgrade just to previous kernel:  `4.8.0.40.51` to `4.8.0.39.50`. Should any package be so strict on kernel version?

Comment: And what does `apt full-upgrade` do?

Comment: @muru exacly the same result. I've added kernel version numbers to question, maybe should downgrade it?

Comment: The package 4.8.0-40 has been deleted from the repository. I don't know why. Presumably a new kernel will be pushed out in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks @bwduncan, You were right, new kernel just arrived. Maybe previous had some issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `linux-image-4.8.0-40-generic` package and related packages were deleted from the repository. I don't know why. A new `linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic` has appeared and the upgrade now goes smooothly.